# Add class to all previous radio buttons and the selected one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am playing with some simple code but can not sort it out :( I would like to add color (class) to the selected radio button and previous ones...for example if button No3 is selected 1,2,3 should get a new color.

here is a simple code

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="1">
            <label for="radio1">one</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="2">
            <label for="radio2">two</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="3">
            <label for="radio3">three</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="4">
            <label for="radio4">four</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="5">
            <label for="radio5">five</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I tried with .prevAll() but obviously it did not work.

here is the current script that adds class to all buttons

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
        $('form ul li input[type=radio] + label').addClass('abc');
    })  
});
```

demo
https://jsfiddle.net/8jct6tfs/2/

should I perhaps use loop? any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why do you call your buttons `radio[]` - why the array brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.closest()` along with `.prevAll()` at this context to archive what you want,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
      $(this).closest("ul").find('li .abc').removeClass("abc");
      $(this).closest("li").prevAll("li").find("label").addClass("abc")
    })  
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8jct6tfs/7/)

Comment: Small Improvement.

    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
        $('.abc').removeClass('abc');
     $(this).closest('li').prevAll('li').find('label').addClass('abc');
 })

Comment: @MaheshKedari What if user has same structure like this throughout his page? If I write like that, then all the elements irrespective of clicked element will be affected.\

Comment: ya it will produce unwanted results.

Answer (score 3):

> Use `.index()` of the `closest` `li` element of the clicked element and Using `:lt`(Elements having smaller index than specified) selector, apply class

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    $('form ul li input[type=radio] + label').removeClass('abc')
    var index = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $('form ul li input[type=radio] + label:lt("' + index + '")').addClass('abc');
  })
});
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
form ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
  position: relative
}
input {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -15px;
  background-color: red;
}
input[type=radio] + label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -15px;
  background-color: gray;
}
label {
  padding-top: 55px;
}
/*this class should be added*/

input[type=radio] + label.abc::before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="1">
      <label for="radio1">one</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="2">
      <label for="radio2">two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="3">
      <label for="radio3">three</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="4">
      <label for="radio4">four</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="5">
      <label for="radio5">five</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8jct6tfs/5/)

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this with help of **[`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)** , **[`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent)** and **[`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
    $('form ul li label').removeClass('abc');
    // remove class from all elements
    $(this)
      .siblings('label').addClass('abc')
      // get label of clicked element and add class
      .parent().prevAll()
      // get all previous `li`
      .find('label').addClass('abc');
    // getting `label` inside and adding class to them
  })
});
```

```css
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
form ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
  position: relative
}
input {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -15px;
  background-color: red;
}
input[type=radio] + label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -12px 0 0 -15px;
  background-color: gray;
}
label {
  padding-top: 55px;
}
/*this class should be added*/

input[type=radio] + label.abc::before {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="1">
      <label for="radio1">one</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="2">
      <label for="radio2">two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="3">
      <label for="radio3">three</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="4">
      <label for="radio4">four</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="5">
      <label for="radio5">five</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
$(this).addClass('abc');

})  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u21cmnp1/

Comment: i think this is you what you needed,if not pleas forgive me for misundrestanding your question

Answer (score 0):

No javascript needed!

I found a way to style all previous siblings (opposite of ~) that may work depending on what you need.

Let's say you have a list of links and when hovering on one, all the previous ones should turn red. You can do it like this:

```
/* default link color is blue */
.parent a {
  color: blue;
}

/* prev siblings should be red */
.parent:hover a {
  color: red;
}
.parent a:hover,
.parent a:hover ~ a {
  color: blue;
}
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aquadk/5ekjo5nx/4/

Answer (score 0):

While you have numerous answers already, I thought I'd offer an alternative that takes care of deselecting the no-longer relevant elements, should a 'lower value' radio be selected:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  // binding to the 'change' event, rather than the 'click'
  // in order that using the <label> will also work to 
  // update the user-interface:
  $("input[type=radio]").on('change', function() {

    // finding the first ancestor <li> element, caching it
    // because we'll use it twice:
    var li = $(this).closest('li');

    // selects all the previous siblings of the <li>,
    // adds the original <li> back to the collection
    // and adds the 'abc' class-name to all selected
    // elements:
    li.prevAll().addBack().addClass('abc');

    // selects all subsequent sibling elements of the
    // original <li>, and removes the 'abc' class-name:
    li.nextAll().removeClass('abc');
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("input[type=radio]").on('change', function() {
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    li.prevAll().addBack().addClass('abc');
    li.nextAll().removeClass('abc');
  });
});
```

```css
.abc {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="1">
      <label for="radio1">one</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="2">
      <label for="radio2">two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="3">
      <label for="radio3">three</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="4">
      <label for="radio4">four</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="5">
      <label for="radio5">five</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xnkxkq6u/).

Further, if we detect the change on the ancestor `<li>` element, it becomes a little more compact and simple (in that we don't have to subsequently find the ancestor, using either `closest()` or `parent()`):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  // as the 'change' event bubbles upwards
  // through the DOM it can be detected on
  // the ancestor <li> element:
  $('li').on('change', function() {

    // caching the <li> element for re-use:
    var li = $(this);

    // exactly as above:
    li.prevAll().addBack().addClass('abc');
    li.nextAll().removeClass('abc');
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('li').on('change', function() {
    var li = $(this);

    li.prevAll().addBack().addClass('abc');
    li.nextAll().removeClass('abc');
  });
});
```

```css
.abc {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="1">
      <label for="radio1">one</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="2">
      <label for="radio2">two</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="3">
      <label for="radio3">three</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="4">
      <label for="radio4">four</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="radio[]" value="5">
      <label for="radio5">five</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xnkxkq6u/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
    //getting the clicked value
    last_value = $(this).val();
    //looping each radio input
    $("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
        //if value of the input is <= last_value, apply the class, else remove the class
        if($(this).val() <= last_value)
        {
            $(this).addClass('abc');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass('abc');
        }
    })  
})
```